# How can I make my chat filter send one embed if there are 2 swear words?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm having an issue where if there are 2 swear words in a message, it will send 2 embeds. Does anyone know fixes for this?

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):    
    for bad_word in bad_words:
        if bad_word in message.content.lower().split(" "):
            t = discord.Embed(color=0x039e00, title="Message Removed", description=f":x:   Please don't say that here, {message.author.mention}.")
            t.set_footer(text="DM TheSuperRobert2498#2498 for bot suggestions.")
            await message.channel.send(embed=t, delete_after=5)
            await message.delete()
        else:
            await client.process_commands(message)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add a `break` after `await message.delete()` to break out of the `bad_words` for loop:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):    
    for bad_word in bad_words:
        if bad_word in message.content.lower().split(" "):
            # ...
            await message.delete()
            break
        else:
            await client.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: Thanks! This fixed it!